# Spring jpql query validation failed for constructor method on spring boot 2.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing some problems about spring boot version. 
When I used the older version of spring boot, 2.1.6.RELEASE, the following query passed query validator and works well as intended.

```
@Query("select new a.b.c.CustomDto(entity) from Entity entity where ...")
Page<CustomDto> getCustomDtoList(@Param("parameter1") ..., Pageable pageable);
```

But after I bumped up the spring boot version to 2.3.0, it occurs QuerySyntaxException which means it seems not to allow such a syntax of writing query.

More specifically, the error occurs when the hibernate generates **count query** for the given query. seriously, it says "unexpected token: count".

Can't I use this syntax anymore on 2.3.0 of spring jpa? TIA.

Comment: How does CustomDto look like? For me it doesn't make sense to pass the whole entity to the constructor. So you don't have any benefits from projection

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Spring Data JPA. Can you please create an issue in https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It's just POJO and of course it has such a constructor with the Entity type parameter. 
That projection is just for simplifying process to send the result to client. But there are more complex cases that should use multiple number of query result as parameter, so I need to use this syntax..

Comment: Did you add  a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-validation` in your build file. It was removed in version to 2.3.0, so you have to manually add it

Comment: The point with the entity as the parameter is that you don't benefit from the constructor expression and I also assume that this causes the exception. You should only pass the attributes to the constructor that you really need!

Comment: @ntholi thanks for your comment, but sadly it appears no changes

Comment: This is https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1587

Comment: I got it. Thank all of you guys!!